# Is the minimized sum greater than the sum of the minimum values?

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Does $$\min_{x \in X} \sum_{t=1}^n f_t(x) \geq \sum_{t=1}^n\min_{x \in X} {f_t(x)}$$  hold?
This is a conclusion I want to use and I feel it's right but I can't prove.
Is it true?
Note: **f is convex in X**

Comment: Hint: $\;\sum_{t=1}^n \left(\underbrace{f_t(x) - \min_{y \in X} {f_t(y)}}_{\ge\, 0}\right) \geq 0\,$ for all $\,\forall x \in X\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds, no matter how the $f_t$ are defined. The left hand side cannot be smaller than the right hand side.

Proof: No matter what argument $y\in X$ minimizes the left hand side, you can always make the right hand side at least as small by choosing $y$ as the argument $n$ times in the sum.